# WORKDIR $HOME in Dockerfile does not seem to work

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile that contains two `WORKDIR` statements (amid other ones) like so:

```
RUN pwd # reports /root
WORKDIR /tmp
RUN wget ...
RUN tar zxvf ...
RUN cd ... && ; ./configure && make && make install 
RUN sed ...
RUN sed ...
RUN rm ...
RUN rm -fr ...
WORKDIR $HOME
RUN pwd # reports /tmp (instead of /root)
```

I would expect `pwd` to be `/root` (i.e. `$HOME` for `root`) afterwards, but it remains at `/tmp`. Am I making an obvious mistake here? Is there a better way for restoring `pwd` to its "original" value.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Seems like the best way would be to explicitly set your own default value so you can be sure it's consistent, like:

```
ENV HOME /root

WORKDIR $HOME
.. do something in /root ..

WORKDIR /tmp
.. do something else in /tmp ..

WORKDIR $HOME
.. continue back in /root ..
```

Note:

> The WORKDIR instruction can resolve environment variables previously
>   set using ENV. You can only use environment variables explicitly set
>   in the Dockerfile.
>
> > https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/workdir

Comment: If you _are_ setting the value for $HOME in the Dockerfile, please post the rest of the file so we can see what's going on.

Comment: Added additional parts of the Dockerfile.

Comment: @Drux, I don't see a `ENV HOME ...` in your included Dockerfile.

Comment: @BMitch I posted the version that does not use it. If I follow your suggestion, it would work. But I am still interested in why Dockerfile does not have access to `$HOME` without me having to set a specific value at its level.

Comment: Relying on external environment variables would mean each build of the same Dockerfile could result in a different image. That would be a bad thing for consistency.

Comment: I see, so it's apparently [another instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38426352/basic-docker-container-reports-runlevel-unknown) of the inside of a container is different from the inside of a VM image by design. Thx, so I assume @ldg's answer (with `ENV HOME /root`) is the way too go then.