# Basic Docker container reports runlevel unknown

Tags: ubuntu, docker, debian, runlevel, google-cloud-shell

When I run a basic Docker container (from within Google Cloud Shell) like so

```
docker pull debian
docker run -i -t debian:wheezy /bin/bash
```

and then type `runlevel` at the running container's shell prompt, the run level is `unknown`. Am I supposed to install (`apt-get`) particular packages in order to add support for run levels. If so, which ones, or what else could be wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Docker is an application isolation tool, not an OS virtualization tool. Runlevels are at the OS level, the OS comes up, mounts directories, and starts services to achieve a runlevel. In a container, your application is launched, the end. You can assume the container is at a single user run level, since you're the only user accessing the environment, but it really shouldn't matter for installing applications.

Comment: I see, looks as if I made the same rookie mistake as also of issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27154567/ubuntu-12-04-into-docker-service-mysql-start). Can you perhaps point to an article that explains further about the difference between the application isolation tool and an OS virtualization tool, so I can learn in a systematic way what else may be different inside a container opposite an VM image?

Comment: The question on the [differences between Docker and VMs](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16047306/596285) is old but may still be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

BMitch is right.  Docker has nothing to do with runlevels, it will never change a runlevel.  But there is more.

`runlevel` `unknown` is common on some systems running `systemd`.  Your question is tagged with Debian though, and Debian Jessie (the latest Debian release, which uses systemd, uses compatibility script to print a runlevel).  Arch based distros, and the unstable RedHat based distros (e.g. Fedora) print `unknown` when executing `runlevel`, i.e. they do not even care to print a fake runlevel.

If you check your runlevel script you will get the following output on a recent distro:

```
$ ls -l $(which runlevel)
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Jun 18 14:44 /usr/bin/runlevel -> systemctl
```

(that is on arch, `runlevel` is in `/usr/sbin` on Debian, but it also points to `systemctl` on Debian)

The `runlevel` script points to `sysemtd` control on most recent distros.

In general `runlevel` has no meaning on recent distros (because of `systemd` to which pretty much everyone switched to).  If you look inside the `/etc/rc.d/rc*.d/` directories, they're almost empty.

What is actually defining how `init` processes the system boot is the systemd default target, located here:

```
/lib/systemd/system/default.target
```

Or `/etc/systemd/system/default.target`, if that exists.