# Best practice re running bash for attaching to Docker running instance

Tags: security, docker

Here is another question from a Docker newbie. I currently run my Docker image in "debugging mode" with `bash` so that I can `docker attach` to the running instance to enter a shell where I can inspect the application’s OS environment, etc., at runtime.

```
docker run <image-id> -d -it bash -c “<start application in background>; bash”
```

I am wondering whether I should have `bash` always included, i.e. change the `CMD` inside `Dockerfile` from `CMD <start application in foreground>` to `CMD <start application in background>; bash`.

Would this be inappropriate in "production mode"

1. for security reasons -- Who is allowed to attach to a running instance?,
2. in light of Docker being an [application isolation tool, not an OS virtualization tool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38426440/1789384),
3. for other reasons?

Comment: Don't do this in production. What are you running in the app? You generally want your app to be the front-most process (PID 1), not `bash`. You want to get used to treating containers like set-and-forget -- or at least not something you need to access manually once it's in production. The whole [Cattle vs Kittens](https://www.google.com/search?q=docker%2Bcattle%2Bvs%2Bkittens) thing.

Comment: Additionally, you ideally want your dev containers to be the same as your production ones, so I wouldn't even use that `bash` approach in dev other than for a temporary testing situation. You can always `docker exec ...` into the container later if need be.

Comment: @ldg Excellent. (As a newbie I did not yet know about `docker exec`. If you want to write up your comment as an answer I shall promptly accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do this in production.

You want your app to be the front-most process (PID 1), not bash.

Ideally your dev containers would be the same as your production ones, so I wouldn't even use that bash approach in dev other than for a temporary testing situation. You can always [docker exec](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) into the container later if need be. E.g.,

`docker exec -it {container-name} /bin/bash`

Where:

> ```
> >   -i, --interactive    Keep STDIN open even if not attached
> >   -t, --tty            Allocate a pseudo-TTY
> ```

Change the name of the executable as needed (e.g., `/bin/sh`, etc.). You many need to set the TERM environment variable for some containers. (e.g., `export TERM=xterm`).

To just return a result and close, leave out the `-it` like:

`docker exec {container-name} ifconfig`

You want to get used to treating containers like set-and-forget -- or at least not something you need to access manually once it's in production.